# Get associated value from enumeration without switch/case

Tags: swift, enums

I've got an enumeration with a few different cases which are different types, e.g.

```
enum X {
    case AsInt(Int)
    case AsDouble(Double)
}
```

I can `switch` on these just fine to get the underlying value back out. However, the `switch` statement is highly annoying with trying to make me execute some code for the other cases that I simply don't care about. For example, right now I have something like

```
func AsInt(x: X) -> Int? {
    switch x {
    case AsInt(let num):
        return num;
    default:
        return nil;
    }
}
```

This works but it's pretty tedious always having to reference this method and having to write a new one for each case of each enumeration. What I'm looking for is how to simply attempt to cast a value of type `X` to one of the cases, like

```
var object: X = func();
let value = obj as? Int;
if value {
    // do shit
}
```

How can I simply check for a case without having to enumerate all of the cases about which I don't care and execute some non-statement for them?

Bonus points for any solution that can declare `value` as part of the conditional instead of polluting the scope.

Comment: You don't need semicolons in Swift.

Comment: ASI is a complete bugfest.

Answer (score 16):

There are actually multiple ways to do it.

Let's do it by extending your enum with a computed property:

```
enum X {
    case asInt(Int)
    case asDouble(Double)

    var asInt: Int? {
        // ... see below
    }
}
```

### Solutions with `if case`

By having `let` outside:

```
var asInt: Int? {
    if case let .asInt(value) = self {
        return value
    }
    return nil
}
```

By having `let` inside:

```
var asInt: Int? {
    if case .asInt(let value) = self {
        return value
    }
    return nil
}
```

### Solutions with `guard case`

By having `let` outside:

```
var asInt: Int? {
    guard case let .asInt(value) = self else {
        return nil
    }
    return value
}
```

By having `let` inside:

```
var asInt: Int? {
    guard case .asInt(let value) = self else {
        return nil
    }
    return value
}
```

The last one is my personal favorite syntax of the four solutions.

Comment: Thanks, looks as a nice solution to me.

Comment: This is a pretty weird little rough corner of Swift.

Answer (score 8):

As of Swift 2 (Xcode 7) this is possible with `if/case` and 
pattern matching:

```
let x : X = ...
if case let .AsInt(num) = x {
    print(num)
}
```

The scope of `num` is restricted to the if-statement.

Comment: In Swift 1.2: `if let num:Int = {switch $0 {case .AsInt(let num): return num; default: return nil}}(x) {` he says in jest.

Comment: I intend to upgrade to Swift 2 as soon as feasible; but I will leave the question open for anybody with a proper Swift 1 solution.

Comment: @Puppy: Swift 2 is the officially released version now, Swift 1.x is history :)

Comment: Totally missed this duplicate, perhaps its title was a bit to mysterious for me :)

Comment: @dfri: Sure, I just happened to know about it :) – I have edited the title to make it hopefully better searchable.