# Determine which Enum in associated enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I've created an associated Enum, however i can't seem to figure out how to create an `if else` statement, which determine which. it does not seem to work, what i'm doing. What am i doing wrong? or is it not possible with associated enums.

```
enum Type {
    case Cat(name: String, outDoor: Bool)
    case Dog(name: String, activityLevel: Int)
}
```

**class**

```
class Person {
    var type: Type?
}
```

**Function**

```
func checkType(object: Person) {
    if object.type == .Cat {
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [Try cast an enum to an enumeration case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698632/try-cast-an-enum-to-an-enumeration-case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a switch statement, unless you are using Swift 2.0 which has the new `if case` statement for this very purpose.

```
enum Type {
    case Cat(name: String, outDoor: Bool)
    case Dog(name: String, activityLevel: Int)
}
class Person {
    var type: Type?
}
func checkType(obj:Person) {
    if let type = obj.type {
        if case .Cat(name:let n, outDoor:let o) = type {
            print(n)
            print(o)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep getting `type of expression is ambigouys without more context`

Comment: Alternatively:  `if case let .Cat(name: n, outDoor: o) = ...` or just `if case let .Cat(n, o) = ...`

Comment: You can even incorporate the optional binding into the pattern matching: `if case let .Cat(n, o)? = obj.type`

Comment: @MartinR Agreed, but I deliberately wanted to show the fullest form. In reality, I find it so hard to think of any other reason to use `if case` (even though in fact _any_ switch case pattern is legal) that I think of it and use it as `if case let` all in one breath.