# Extract value from enum using guard or if case in Swift

Tags: swift

I have enum with cases:

```
case one(value: myClassOne)
case two(value: myClassTwo)
```

I want to check value of that enum. Now i ended with:

```
switch self.model! {
case .one:
    // Great, my case here
default:
    break
}
```

But i rather want to do something like:

```
if case self.model(let value) is myClassOne { // do smth } // Not compiling
```

Is there is easy way to simply extract enum value and check it for some condition or class equality?

Comment: Do you mean this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31698974 ? – In your case it should be something like `if case let .one(value) = self.model { use value ... }`

Comment: @MartinR i have look at this question but i dont understand, if case let .AsInt(num) = x {
    print(num)
} have no reference to variable that store enum, in my case - self.model. Could you please provide similiar example?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
if case .one(value: let value) = self.model {
    // do something with `value`
}

guard case .one(value: let value) = self.model else {
    //handle case where self.model != .one
}
// do something with `value`
```